# It can't free memory of an actionBar

Tags: android, memory, android-actionbar

I have a actionbar with navigation mode NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST.

```
    Resources recursos = this.getResources();
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST);
    ArrayAdapter adaptador = new TipoPincelAdapter(this, R.layout.spinner_tipos_pinceles_layout, recursos.getStringArray(R.array.codigo_tipo_lapiz) );
    actionBar.setListNavigationCallbacks(adaptador, this);
```

I finish() the activity. If I load this activity other time, and come back to finish it, I see that I have two references to the actionbar in MAT.

### Class Name                                                           | Shallow Heap | Retained Heap | Percentage

> com.innovativeproject.firstletters.Lienzo1Activity @ 0xb5db4ec0      |
>   264 |        66.144 |      0,19% |-
>   com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarView @ 0xb5d1bb58            |
>   600 |        21.416 |      0,06% |  |- android.widget.Spinner @
>   0xb5db3bd8                            |          600 |         4.384 |
>   0,01% |  |  |- android.view.View[12] @ 0xb5d2c870
>   |           64 |         2.640 |      0,01% |  |  |-
>   android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable @ 0xb5ce05e8    |
>   88 |           696 |      0,00% |  |  |-
>   android.widget.AbsSpinner$RecycleBin @ 0xb5ce08a8           |
>   16 |           168 |      0,00% |  |  |-
>   android.view.InputEventConsistencyVerifier @ 0xb5ce0568     |
>   80 |           104 |      0,00% |  |  |-
>   android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams @ 0xb5ce0b60       |
>   56 |            56 |      0,00% |  |  |-
>   android.view.animation.Transformation @ 0xb5ce0810          |
>   24 |            24 |      0,00% |  |  |- android.graphics.Rect @
>   0xb5ce0888                          |           24 |            24 |
>   0,00% |  |  |- android.graphics.Rect @ 0xb5ce08e0
>   |           24 |            24 |      0,00% |  |  |-
>   android.graphics.PointF @ 0xb5ce0860                        |
>   16 |            16 |      0,00% |  |  |- android.view.ViewGroup$3 @
>   0xb5ce0878                       |           16 |            16 |
>   0,00% |  |  |- android.widget.AdapterView$SelectionNotifier @
>   0xb5ce5720   |           16 |            16 |      0,00% |  |  '-
>   Total: 11 entries                                           |
>   |               |            |  |-
>   com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarView$HomeView @ 0xb5db60e0|
>   472 |         3.944 |      0,01% |  |-
>   com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarView$HomeView @ 0xb5d10958|
>   472 |         3.360 |      0,01%

---

How can I free the actionbar to avoid increasing the memory?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

From the source code, `ActionBarView` has two attributes of type `HomeView`

```
private HomeView mHomeLayout;
private HomeView mExpandedHomeLayout;
```

`HomeView` is an inner class. This is probably what you are seeing, in any case you shouldn't worry about your views "increasing the memory", views will be destroyed by android as soon as it sees fit.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've tried 10 times in and out of the activity and never deletes any reference to actionbar, and creates 10 new references. The application work with big images and finally I  get an outofmemory.

Comment: Clear the references to these images, and any other large objects such as database connections before you finish, e.g if you have a global/member reference to a bitmap, set it to null, its not the views causing you to run out of memory

Comment: the problem was caused by Samsung SDK Pen. I clear and put to null all references and free the drawable objects. Too, I clear the SCanvasView, but, it's not working. I update my application to SDK 2.2 and I don't find any reference to actionBar. Thank you very much.